# Python connected components with pixel list

Tags: python, image, pixel, connected-components

In matlab you can use

```
cc = bwconncomp(bimg);
pixels = cc.PixelIdxList{i}
```

To get pixel list of each connected components. What's the python equivalent?
I tried

```
from skimage import measure
label = measure.label(bimg)
```

To get the labels, however, this does not come with pixel list.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [regionprops](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) function in scikit-image returns the property "coords", an (N, 2) ndarray coordinate list (row, col) of the region. I ran into the same problem and am using this to get the pixel list from the label array.

Answer (score 1):

To get pixel list of a connected component with some_label (e.g. some_label=1), if you have a labeled image:

```
pixels = numpy.argwhere(labeled_image == some_label)
```

See [numpy.argwhere](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html).

And see also this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487437/coordinates-of-item-on-numpy-array).